# Check if a class implements a exact generic class definition

Tags: c#

So what I'm trying is to make a method that selects types that implement a generic class, with specific generic value that is only known at run-time.

I have tried something like this

```cs
public bool HasCommand(ITerminal owner)
{
    var genericType = typeof(Command<>).MakeGenericType(owner.GetType());
    var command = typeof(HelloCommand);

    return command.GetInterfaces().Any(x => x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericType 
                                            && x.IsGeneric); 
}
```

And hello command looks like this

```cs
public class HelloCommand : Command<HallTerminal>
```

But it always returns false.
Any solutions on what to change / do.

**EDIT** :
The command class looks like this

```
public class Command<T>
```

Comment: I'm just guessing, but maybe GetGenericTypeDefinition is returning a different instance of Type than your typeof. In this case using equals should help.

Comment: You're calling `GetInterfaces()` - but `Command<T>` isn't an interface. I suspect the `is` operator is what you want though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem, but the issue of always getting false was that `Command` (which is implemented in HelloCommand) is not a interfence, hence always false.

To solve this issue you can do

```cs
command.BaseType.IsEquivalentTo(genericType)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether the class is compatible with a given type using `is` operator:

```
public bool HasCommand(Terminal owner)
{ 
    var gType = typeof(Command<>).MakeGenericType(owner.GetType());
    var bType = typeof(HelloCommand);

    if (owner is Command<HallTerminal>) 
    {     

    }
}
```

An example:

```
public class Person<T>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }            
}

public class Student : Person<Greeting>
{   }

public class StudentWarmGreeting : Person<WarmGreeting>
{   }        

public class Greeting 
{
    public void SayHello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, it is Greeting!:)");
    }
}

public class WarmGreeting
{
    public void SayHello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, it is WarmGreeting!:)");
    }
}
```

And you can check using `is` operator:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (studentGreeting is Person<Greeting>)
            Console.WriteLine("person is Greeting");

    if (studentWarmGreeting is Person<WarmGreeting>)
            Console.WriteLine("person is WarmGreeting");

    // Visual Studio is clever and it will say:
    // "The given expression is never of the provided ('Program.Person') type"
    if (studentWarmGreeting is Person<Greeting>)
            Console.WriteLine("person is Greeting");
}
```

However, Visual Studio is clever and it will give a warning to us:

> The given expression is never of the provided
>   ('Program.Person') type

Comment: I think i didn't made it clear, so i want to check if a type that implements the `Command` class has a **specific** generic value. In this case it is `HallTerminal` (Command<HallTerminal>), but that might change into `RoomTerminal` (Command<RoomTerminal>).

Comment: @SuPEr_Toaster_Official please, see my updated answer